# Uri rerouting codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am struggle with URI rerouting in my codeigniter version(2.2.0)application.

Here is my routes.php

```
$route['details/(:num)'] = 'agent/manage_agents/$1';
```

And in my view file

```
foreach($data as $value) {?>

<a href="<?php base_url();?>details/<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Manage</a>
}?>
```

But i will get 404 error.

In my Controller file

```
class Agent extends CI_Controller {

   public function manage_agents($id)
    {
        echo $id;
    }   
}
```

**UPDATE**
Finally i found Which causes the problem.In my routes.php

```
$route['(:any)'] = "spotmyticket/$1"; when hide this line everything works  fine.
```

Here is my complete routes.php

$route['404_override'] = '';

```
$route['default_controller'] = "spotmyticket";
$route['ticket']="ticket";
$route['ticket/(:any)'] = $route['ticket'].'/$1';

$route['captcha'] = "captcha"; 
$route['captcha/(:any)'] = "captcha/$1";
$route['admin'] = "admin"; 
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1";
$route['userdashboard'] = "userdashboard";
$route['userdashboard/(:any)'] = "userdashboard/$1"; 
$route['fbci'] = "fbci"; 
$route['fbci/(:any)'] = "fbci/$1";

$route['(:any)'] = "spotmyticket/$1";

$route['agent-management'] = 'agent/index';
$route['register'] = "agent/agent_register";
$route['test'] = 'agent/test';
$route['details/(:any)'] = 'agent/manage_agents/$1';
```

Comment: You haven't given enough information for people to help you.
What version of CI are you using? What is the URI you're trying to hit?

Comment: @ Relequestual I've edited my question

Comment: From docs: `Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please define `$route['(:any)'] = "spotmyticket/$1";` as the last rule in routes.php. Everything will be fine. This rule is for any url so all rules defined after this rule will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing this route:

```
$route['details/(:num)'] = 'agent/manage_agents/$1';
```

so that you may pass any integer value (like you are passing $value['id']), then try using (:any) instead of (:num). So your route should be:

```
$route['details/(:any)'] = 'agent/manage_agents/$1';
```

Comment: Can you try once: <?php echo base_url('details');?>/<?php echo $value['id']; ?> instead of <?php base_url();?>details/<?php echo $value['id']; ?> and use it with the route (:num) ??

Comment: Or, you can have them all inside a single echo as <?php echo base_url('details') .'/' .$value['id'];?>

Comment: Tried,but again the same:)

Comment: okk, can you try <?php echo site_url('details') .'/' .$value['id'];?>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98834/discussion-between-captain-red-and-blessan-kurien).